# model.parameters() alternative for TransUNet from transunet python library

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement TransUNet for breakhis dataset I was making the optimizer like this

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
```

my model is

```
from transunet import TransUNet
model = TransUNet(image_size=224, pretrain=True)
```

But the `parameter()` function does not work with TransUNet

This is the library I am using https://github.com/awsaf49/TransUNet-tf

I tried using `named_parameter()`, `__dict__['parameters']`,`state_dict()` but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TransUNet` model from `transunet` Library is implemented in TensorFlow and `.parameters()` is a torch function.

For TensorFlow we can use something like this -

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```